# select the max(date) and table name as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have many tables like:

1. `A_names`  ( updated_at date  )
2. `B_names` (updated_at date )
3. `C_names` (updated_at date )

I want max of updated_date and table name for all the table like `'%names%'` in the database

```
 select * into #temp1 
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME  like '%names%'
```

How to do it ..? thanks in advance

Comment: out put like 
Table_name Max(Updated_At) from table
A_Names         2013-01-25 06:39:45.550
B_Names         2013-01-21 10:59:59.737
C_Names         2013-01-20 10:59:59.737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically create a SQL statement and then run that command.

```
DECLARE @dml nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @dml += ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' + name + ''' AS tableName, MAX(updated_at) AS maxUpdated_at FROM ' 
               + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name like '%names%'
PRINT @dml
SET @dml = STUFF(@dml, 1, 10, '')
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```

Option without a STUFF function

```
DECLARE @dml nvarchar(max)
SELECT @dml = ISNULL(@dml + ' UNION ALL', '') + ' SELECT ''' + name + ''' AS tableName, MAX(updated_at) AS maxUpdated_at FROM ' 
              + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name like '%names%'
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
 Select name ,modify_date from sys.tables
 where name like '%names'
```

And avoid using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` instead use catalog views .

Check this article out [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Comment: many tables ends with _names, and all table contains updated_at column as one of column i want table name and its max(updated_at) where table name ends with _names

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(updated_at_date)
FROM table1
```

I'm a bit confused from the description about your table names. Anyways this is the way you select the max date.

Answer (score 0):

Probabaly Praveen's answer is a solution to your problem, but in pseudocode

```
     DECLARE @SqlStmt NVARCHAR(2000)

     For Each TableName in 'Select name from sys.tables'
     {
        if @SqlStmnt <> '' @SqlStmnt = @SqlStmnt + ' UNION '

        @sqlStmnt = @sqlStmnt + ' SELECT Max(updated_at_date) AS MAXDATE FROM ' + TableName 
     }

     **EXECUTE ('SELECT MAX(MAXDATE) FROM (' + @SqlStmt + ')')**
```